# JS: forEach item in array current value

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array of items being called by a forEach. I want to get the value of the current item, every time there's an iteration. How can i do that?

```
var bottom_array = [41,42,43,44]
bottom_array.forEach(function(){
    console.log(*current item*);
    })

console> 41
console> 42
console> 43
console> 44
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're expected to have done *some* research before posting questions here. It's impossible for you to have not discovered the answer if you'd made *any* attempt to do so. https://www.google.ca/search?q=javascript+array+foreach&oq=javascript+array+foreach&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.6828j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Before you use an unfamiliar method, **read its documentation**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I've searched stackoverflow and the mozilla documentation. I guess i couldn't figure out the callback WAS the place for the value

Comment: The examples are pretty clear IMO: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`forEach` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) invokes the given callback with a set of arguments which allow you to access the current value, among other things.

Those arguments are:

1. The current value (this is what you want)
2. The current index
3. A reference to the array

You can get what you want by adding a single argument to your callback function, since you don't need the others:

```
bottom_array.forEach(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bottom_array.forEach(function(i){
    console.log(i);
    });
```